# Firebase Realtime DB: Order query results by number of values for a key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase web Realtime DB with users, each of whom has a `jobs` attribute whose value is an object:

```
{
  userid1:
    jobs:
      guid1: {},
      guid2: {},
  userid2:
    jobs:
      guid1: {},
      guid2: {},
}
```

I want to query to get the n users with the most jobs. Is there an orderby trick I can use to order the users by the number of values the given user has in their `jobs` attribute?

I specifically don't want to store an integer count of the number of jobs each user has because I need to update users' `jobs` attribute as a part of atomic updates that update other user attributes concurrently and atomically, and I don't believe transactions (like incrementing/decrementing counters) can be a part of those atomic transactions.

Here's an example of the kind of atomic update I'm doing. Note I don't have the user that I'm modifying in memory when I run the following update:

```
firebase.database().ref('/').update({
  [`/users/${user.guid}/pizza`]: true,
  [`/users/${user.guid}/jobs/${job.guid}/scheduled`]: true,
})
```

Any suggestions on patterns that would work with this data would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: you can use getChildren

Comment: @Ticherhaz could you by chance send a little example of what you have in mind?

Comment: With the Realtime Database you cannot query ordered by an aggregate function as you would do in the SQL world. The classical approach is indeed to maintain a counter. Why do you think you could not integrate this counter management business logic in your atomic updates? Can you share the code of those "atomic updates that update other user attributes concurrently and atomically"? (Needless to mention that the option of downloading the entire tree and sort it in the front end is not a good one...)

Comment: Note that you could also update the counter in a Cloud Function, from the back-end, without interfering with your atomic updates.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thanks for confirming--I was afraid of that. My atomic updates are just as you'd imagine -- I'll post an example above. Trouble is I don't know the count value of the records I need to modify at update time--I just need to send a +1 or -1 command to the db, rather than a setter command that sets the count to X, as I won't know the current count value when it's time to update the record. Does that make sense? Is there indeed a way to send a +1 request in an atomic update, either from a web client or cloud function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realtime Database transactions run on a single node in the JSON tree, so it would be quite difficult to integrate the update of a `jobCounter` node within your atomic update to several nodes (i.e. to  `/users/${user.guid}/pizza` and `/users/${user.guid}/jobs/${job.guid}/scheduled`). We would need to update at `/users/${user.guid}` level and calculate the counter value, etc...

An easier approach is to use a Cloud Function to update a user's `jobCounter` node each time there is a change to one of the `jobs` nodes that implies a change in the counter. In other words, if a new job node is added or removed, the counter is updated. If an existing node is only modified, the counter is not updated, since there were no change in the number of jobs.

```
exports.updateJobsCounter = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/jobs')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

        if (!change.after.exists()) {

            //This is the case when no more jobs exist for this user

            const userJobsCounterRef = change.before.ref.parent.child('jobsCounter');
            return userJobsCounterRef.transaction(() => {
                return 0;
            });

        } else {

            if (!change.before.val()) {

                //This is the case when the first job is created

                const userJobsCounterRef = change.before.ref.parent.child('jobsCounter');
                return userJobsCounterRef.transaction(() => {
                    return 1;
                });

            } else {

                const valObjBefore = change.before.val();
                const valObjAfter = change.after.val();

                const nbrJobsBefore = Object.keys(valObjBefore).length;
                const nbrJobsAfter = Object.keys(valObjAfter).length;

                if (nbrJobsBefore !== nbrJobsAfter) {
                    //We update the jobsCounter node
                    const userJobsCounterRef = change.after.ref.parent.child('jobsCounter');
                    return userJobsCounterRef.transaction(() => {
                        return nbrJobsAfter;
                    });
                } else {
                    //No need to update the jobsCounter node
                    return null;
                }

            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: Spectacular answer! Boy this is easier in SQL! Thanks one million @RenaudTarnec, this is super helpful